# in the same query where and like zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-table

Where to make a query like this, how can I do?

```
SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE name LIKE '%mykey%' AND country_id = '12'
```

I have done so, but we must not:

```
$select = $this->sql->select();
$select->from(self::TABLE);  

if ($params['key'])
{
   $where['where'] = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('name', '%'.$params['key'].'%');
}

if($params['country_id'])
{
  $where['where'] = array(
      'country_id' => $params['country_id']
  );
}

$select->where($where['where']);
$select->order('id DESC');
$statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
return $statement->execute();
```

are obliged to make the if statement to change the behavior of the query.
How can I do?

Comment: I don't understand what do you ask ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$select = $this->sql->select();
$select->from(self::TABLE);  

if ($params['key'])
{
    $select->where->like('name', '%'.$params['key'].'%');
}

if($params['country_id'])
{
    $select->where(array('country_id' => $params['country_id']));
}

$select->order('id DESC');
$statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
return $statement->execute();
```